# What's the difference between <%= %> and <%# %>?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, data-binding

I tried to find what the difference is between these two with Google, but I could not find an exact definition, and I could not exactly search for symbols either.

Right now I know that you can put a piece of code between <%# %> and you have to call Page.DataBind() method to apply it, I think this is how <%# %> works. But what does <%= %> mean? When should I use it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Basic differences are:

The `<%= %>` expressions are evaluated at render time.

The `<%# %>` expressions are evaluated at `DataBind()` time and are not evaluated at all if `DataBind()` is not called.

`<%# %>` expressions can be used as properties in server-side controls.

`<%= %>` expressions cannot and are used to reference properties or fields.

For example:

```
<%= Response.Write() %>

<ItemTemplate>
      <%# DataBinder.Eval("Title") %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

You can have a more detailed explanation on msdn here: [What's the difference between <%= %> and <%# %>](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-lt-and-lt-in-asp-net.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: So if I understand correctly from the article you referenced, <%= %> can't be used in server controls because it's written in render time. It's written during the "rendering" part of a page lifecycle: [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: and if you use it in server controls asp.net converts <%= %> to html so then it won't be rendered during render time because asp.net thinks its a part of the html.

Answer (score 4):

- `<%= %>` is used to reference properties/fields. It's like having a `Response.Write` "inlined" in the page at that position.
- `<%# %>` is used for data binding with Eval/Bind. Taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx)

> The Eval method evaluates late-bound data expressions in the templates of data-bound controls such as the GridView, DetailsView,
>   and FormView controls. At run time, the Eval method calls the Eval
>   method of the DataBinder object,

ASP.NET 4.0 introduces `<%: something %>` that is like `<%= %>` but escapes content (so it converts `<` to `&lt;` and so on)

So in the end you can use the <%# %> only in some controls (those that inherit from `BaseDataBoundControl`)

There is an article here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479321.aspx that explains how the data binding is done in .NET

I'll add a link with a list of all the special inline tags of Asp.net: http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-(3c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc).aspx (it doesn't contain `<%: %>`)

Comment: I can also use <%# %> to reference properties/fields why should I use <%= %> instead?

Comment: They are similar but different. Let's say this: you can use `<%= %>` anywhere on the page, and it can reference any field/property/method that could be accessed by a method of that page. You can use `<# %>` only from inside some controls, like `GridView`, and it "connects" to the `DataSource` declared in the `GridView` (or in general to the `BaseDataBoundControl`). With many controls (like `GridView`) not only it connects to the `DataSource` but directly to the current `DataRow`)

Comment: From what I read in this article [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-lt-and-lt-in-asp-net.aspx) you can't use '<%= %>' as attributes of a server control.

Comment: @user1004708 You are right. With "anywhere" I was thinking "anywhere you could write an html control" :-) The explanation in my response was more right `is used to reference properties/fields. It's like having a Response.Write "inlined" in the page at that position.`. Cleary you can't `Response.Write` in a property of a server-side control.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= ... %>
```

Used for small chunks of information, usually from objects and single pieces of information like a single string or int variable:

```
The Date is now <%= DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() %>
The value of string1 is <%= string1 %>
```

[MSDN: Displaying from ASP.NET](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5%28VS.71%29.aspx)

```
<%# .. %>
```

Used for Binding Expressions; such as Eval and Bind, most often found in data controls like GridView, Repeater, etc.:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMeetings" DataSourceID="meetings" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("MeetingName") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

[MSDN: Data-Binding Expressions Overview](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx)

Internet resource: [Inline asp.net tags... sorting them all out](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx)